# Can set a limit for a joined table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to somehow set a `limit 1` for a joined table `masters` but still not change the query much?

```
SELECT "rep_4hours"."hour_id", 
    "rep_4hours"."report_date", 
    "rep_4hours"."createdAt", 
    "rep_4hours"."updatedAt", 
    "rep_4hours"."teams_id", 
    "team"."team_id" AS "team.team_id", 
    "team"."full_name" AS "team.full_name", 
    "team"."is_active" AS "team.is_active", 
    "team"."createdAt" AS "team.createdAt", 
    "team"."updatedAt" AS "team.updatedAt", 
    "team->masters"."master_id" AS "team.masters.master_id", 
    "team->masters"."full_name" AS "team.masters.full_name", 
    "team->masters"."comment" AS "team.masters.comment", 
    "team->masters"."date_work" AS "team.masters.date_work", 
    "team->masters"."createdAt" AS "team.masters.createdAt", 
    "team->masters"."updatedAt" AS "team.masters.updatedAt", 
    "team->masters"."teams_id" AS "team.masters.teams_id" 
    FROM "rep_4hours" AS "rep_4hours" 
    INNER JOIN "teams" AS "team" ON "rep_4hours"."teams_id" = "team"."team_id" 
    INNER JOIN "masters" AS "team->masters" ON "team"."team_id" = "team->masters"."teams_id"
    WHERE ("report_date" >= "date_work") ORDER BY "team->masters"."date_work" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `derived table`(`sub-query`) to limit `masters` data -

```
SELECT "rep_4hours"."hour_id", 
    "rep_4hours"."report_date", 
    "rep_4hours"."createdAt", 
    "rep_4hours"."updatedAt", 
    "rep_4hours"."teams_id", 
    "team"."team_id" AS "team.team_id", 
    "team"."full_name" AS "team.full_name", 
    "team"."is_active" AS "team.is_active", 
    "team"."createdAt" AS "team.createdAt", 
    "team"."updatedAt" AS "team.updatedAt", 
    "team->masters"."master_id" AS "team.masters.master_id", 
    "team->masters"."full_name" AS "team.masters.full_name", 
    "team->masters"."comment" AS "team.masters.comment", 
    "team->masters"."date_work" AS "team.masters.date_work", 
    "team->masters"."createdAt" AS "team.masters.createdAt", 
    "team->masters"."updatedAt" AS "team.masters.updatedAt", 
    "team->masters"."teams_id" AS "team.masters.teams_id" 
    FROM "rep_4hours" AS "rep_4hours" 
    INNER JOIN "teams" AS "team" ON "rep_4hours"."teams_id" = "team"."team_id" 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM "masters" LIMIT 1) AS "team->masters" ON "team"."team_id" = "team->masters"."teams_id"
    WHERE ("report_date" >= "date_work") ORDER BY "team->masters"."date_work" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: I marked this as a solution, but after that I have `ORDER BY "team-> masters". "Date_work" DESC` stops sorting.

Comment: You can move `ORDER BY "masters"."Date_work" DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0` inside sub-query.

Comment: Maybe your `where` clause condition restricting data. Try removing `where` clause condition and check output.

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing a lateral join using `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT
    r.hour_id,
    r.report_date,
    r.createdAt,
    r.updatedAt,
    r.teams_id,
    t.team_id,
    t.full_name,
    t.is_active,
    t.createdAt,
    t.updatedAt,
    m.master_id,
    m.full_name,
    m.comment,
    m.date_work,
    m.createdAt,
    m.updatedAt,
    m.teams_id,
FROM rep_4hours r
INNER JOIN teams t
    ON r.teams_id = t.team_id
INNER JOIN LATERAL
(
    SELECT m1.*
    FROM masters m1
    WHERE m1.teams_id = t.team_id
    ORDER BY <some_col>   -- LIMIT only makes sense with an ORDER BY clause
    LIMIT 1
) m
    ON TRUE
WHERE
    report_date >= date_work
ORDER BY
   m.date_work DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Note that the lateral `LIMIT` subquery really needs to have an `ORDER BY` clause in order for limit to make any sense.  Otherwise, it is not clear *which* first record you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query. limit your masters using a `subquery`, and don't forget to include `order by`

```
SELECT "rep_4hours"."hour_id", 
    "rep_4hours"."report_date", 
    "rep_4hours"."createdAt", 
    "rep_4hours"."updatedAt", 
    "rep_4hours"."teams_id", 
    "team"."team_id" AS "team.team_id", 
    "team"."full_name" AS "team.full_name", 
    "team"."is_active" AS "team.is_active", 
    "team"."createdAt" AS "team.createdAt", 
    "team"."updatedAt" AS "team.updatedAt", 
    "team->masters"."master_id" AS "team.masters.master_id", 
    "team->masters"."full_name" AS "team.masters.full_name", 
    "team->masters"."comment" AS "team.masters.comment", 
    "team->masters"."date_work" AS "team.masters.date_work", 
    "team->masters"."createdAt" AS "team.masters.createdAt", 
    "team->masters"."updatedAt" AS "team.masters.updatedAt", 
    "team->masters"."teams_id" AS "team.masters.teams_id" 
FROM "rep_4hours" AS "rep_4hours" 
INNER JOIN "teams" AS "team" ON "rep_4hours"."teams_id" = "team"."team_id" 
INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM "masters" ORDER BY "date_work" DESC LIMIT 10) AS "team->masters" ON "team"."team_id" = "team->masters"."teams_id"
WHERE ("report_date" >= "date_work");
```